# How to get the choice_text value from the following model in Django

Tags: python, django, list, django-queryset

I have a model like this in Django:

```
class Choice(models.Model):

    question = models.ForeignKey(Question)
    choice_text = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    answer = models.BooleanField(blank=False, default=False)
```

I have a question in a list like this: `[1, 2]`

Now, I want to get the correct answer of that `question`. So, I do like this:

```
>>> for i in question:
...     Choice.objects.filter(question=i, answer=True)
... 
[<Choice: yes>]
[<Choice: ok1>]
```

Instead like this, I want correct answer to be on the list like:

```
correct_answer = ['yes', 'no']
```

How to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of making multiple queries in the loop you can use `in`. Then iterate over results and see if `choice_text` is equal to `yes`:

```
choices = Choice.objects.filter(question_id__in=[1,2], answer=True)
for choice in choices:
    print choice.question_id, choice_text if choice_text == 'yes' else 'no'
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Another option:

```
correct_answer = []
for i in question:
    correct_answer.append(Choice.objects.get(question=i, answer=True).choice_text)
```

Answer (score 0):

if all you want a flat list of just the `choice_text`, you can use `.values_list()` with the `flat=True` parameter. For example:

```
correct_answer = Choice.objects.filter(question=i, answer=True).values_list('choice_text', flat=True)
# correct_answer will be ['yes', 'no'] or whatever the choice_text's are.
```

Here is the documentation on `.values_list()`: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#values-list